# HotChocolate with Entity Framework uses different column/table name on join with projection

Tags: c#, sql-server, hotchocolate

I have a simple very basic API implementation. It returns the data perfectly when using the HotChocolate interface.

However, I want to join data and return it as such when the consumer calls to the endpoint.

When I execute on a projected model, the query sent to the database has a different name than my properties in my model - I cannot find a resource to explain to me why.

Model is absolutely massive, with more than 300 properties, so I am going to just add 2 properties with the `IQueryable` I am attempting to nest with the response.

This is `FlatTable.cs`:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string? UniqueValue { get; set; }
[UseSorting]
public ICollection<ClientAPRole>? IMUK_PAF_ClientAPRoles { get; set; }
```

This is `ClientAPRole.cs`:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string? UniqueValue { get; set; }
public string? Status { get; set; }
```

My simple `dbcontext`:

```
public class FormsAssistDbContext : DbContext
{
    public FormsAssistDbContext(DbContextOptions options) 
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<FlatTable> IMUK_PAF_FlatTable => Set<FlatTable>();
    public DbSet<ClientAPRole> IMUK_PAF_ClientAPRoles => Set<ClientAPRole>();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<FlatTable>()
            .OwnsMany(f => f.IMUK_PAF_ClientAPRoles);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And finally my `Query.cs`:

```
public class Query
{
    [UsePaging]
    [UseProjection]
    [UseFiltering]
    public IQueryable<FlatTable?> GetFlatTables(FormsAssistDbContext context)
        => context.IMUK_PAF_FlatTable;
}
```

From all the guides and resources I've gathered that this should just work.

However, when running this GraphQL query:

```
query GetFlatTables{
  flatTables{
      id
      uniqueValue
      imuk_PAF_ClientAPRoles{
        id
        status
        uniqueValue
      }
  }
}
```

I sometimes get invalid object and sometimes invalid column name from the result (when I don't add the `APRoles` to the `dbcontext`):

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unexpected Execution Error",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "flatTables"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "message": "Invalid object name 'ClientAPRole'.",
        "stackTrace": /.. removed for brevity
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I add the `APRoles` to the `dbcontext`:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unexpected Execution Error",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "flatTables"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "message": "Invalid column name 'FlatTableID'.\r\nInvalid column name 'FlatTableID'.\r\nInvalid column name 'FlatTableID'.",
        "stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__208_0(Task`1 result)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Data.ToListMiddleware`1.InvokeAsync(IMiddlewareContext context)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Resolvers.Expressions.Parameters.ServiceHelper.<>c__DisplayClass7_3`1.<<UseResolverServiceInternal>b__5>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at HotChocolate.Resolvers.Expressions.Parameters.ServiceHelper.<>c__DisplayClass7_1`1.<<UseResolverServiceInternal>b__3>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.ExecuteResolverPipelineAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.TryExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's what the query does:
[image]

It makes the target column MyClass + Column for some reason - I don't know why this behavior is happening based off my code.

I watched a bunch of youtube videos and guides, did some reading up on the main website, tried changing my query to, tried using linq for the join explicitly, and now consulting stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you get these errors when joining data manually using linq? Try to repeat it with resolver that does not have any attribute and returns `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable`. It seems to me that `UseProjection` is not the reason of your headache and the problem lives at the EF configuration level

Comment: I got a similar issue when I tried using linq yes. I'll adjust the code and see what happens with an IENumberable of roles... Thanks